# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've been trying to compile a customized build of an open-source project, but a rather annoying error just continue to pop up for an otherwise unmodified driver project:

```
    crypto_fast.lib(xts_fast.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
    crypto_fast.lib(twofish.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
    crypto_fast.lib(sha512_hmac.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
    crypto_fast.lib(aes_key.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
    crypto_fast.lib(xts_fast.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
    crypto_fast.lib(sha512_pkcs5_2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
```

The list is much longer, I wont include all the log for obvious reasons.

My hypothesis is that the project wont run in Debug mode, because as it seems it hasn't defined the properties, but I think that's trivial since another project is similar in that matter.

Anyways if it where the case that the undefined Debug mode causes the bug, what specific properties needs to be set in order to allow the debugging process of this project? (to this regards I'm basically interested in seeing how the internals run.)

Comment: I would check that you have the same list of `Additional Dependencies` in both `debug` and `release`. Whenever I do anything in the project settings, the first thing I always do is change the drop-down to `All Configurations` for this exact reason.

Comment: I just simply copied the Release config to a new Debug config, and checked that all references are the same. It seems that now the references errors are only limited to the msvcrt.lib.

Comment: Using a static link library can only come to a good end if it was compiled with the same compiler settings you used to build the rest of your code.  This one is a gross mismatch, it was built with typical Debug build settings.  You'll need to obtain another build of the .lib to get a successful and working release build.